# Why doesn't answering reactivate my account for asking questions?

Tags: support, asking-questions, post-ban

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?  (the answer is here, in this post)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)

Last one month I could not ask any questions, getting error message like this.

I referred to [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers) this, in that they have mentioned, "if you want reactivate then have to answer some questions", I did that also, but still I could not ask the question.

Comment: It's implied that your answers are *good* answers, and that they will therefore be voted up. It's not enough to just answer questions.

Comment: yes getting some up votes too for my answers....

Comment: I can't see questions you asked with downvotes , which probably indicate the problem is with **deleted post you have**.

Comment: yes i have deleted some questions, because after posting, i can find the answers within 5 mins. so i gave upvote to that answers and deleted this. I was not aware of this may affect my rights to ask question here...

Comment: @Ponmala. See my answer below. Good luck!

Comment: I would have thought that getting ca 300rep for answers should be enough to lift the question ban

Comment: i think i'm having 300rep for answers

Comment: Please note: Many of your answers are merely links that say, "see this for an answer". You can not expect answers like that to get lots of up-votes, and they can, in fact, be deleted or converted to comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see questions you asked with downvotes , which probably indicate the problem is with **deleted post you have**.

> It's not a problem to have deleted posts. But if a large percentage of your posts are deleted by yourself or the community, then apparently they were not suitable for the site. But meanwhile they might have wasted time from users who read them, or even responded to them. Therefore deleted posts have an effect on the filter, among many other secret factors.

Another option, you got proximity 70 answer out of 90, with zero upvotes, which may indicate a low quality post.

If you really want to know what is the reason for the block, and what you should do, contact the stackoverflow team..

**Update:**

> yes I have deleted some questions, because after posting, i can find the answers within 5 mins. so i gave upvote to that answers and deleted this. I was not aware of this may affect my rights to ask question here...

So it's probably the first option like I thought, maybe undeleting the questions can help.
We can't be sure what is the reason or how you should fix it because:

1. The blocks factors are secrets.
2. Only moderator can see deleted posts, and the amount of flags your account "gained".

Comment: how to see my deleted posts in my account?

Comment: @Ponmalar. I'm afraid you can't do it by your own. You need a link to them. contact the stackoverflow team.

Comment: If you find the solution to a question you ask, ***don't*** delete it, answer it yourself! It will help others.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your responses.